# web browser / plugin with mouse hover mode

Tags: mouse

I'm having problems with websites where the only way to access a page is by hovering over a menu. Is there any way of doing that in android? Maybe an app which allows the screen to be used as if a touch pad on a laptop.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smartphones and tablets have an obvious problem with events like mouseover:  When there’s no mouse cursor, there’s no way to mouse over controls.

Some techniques may be applied as a work around, but it's hard to have them working decently.

---

**Testing:** <sup>*with minimal success*</sup>

Don't know what browser are you using, but with my phone:

> Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; U8510 Build/HuaweiU8510)
>
> AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>
> Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

If I long press the menu that contains a sub-menu presented with mouseover, it opens after about 3 seconds *(even though, every two out of three, the click for the main menu gets triggered)*.

**Ps:**
The website used to test it was developed by me, so I know for sure that there's no support for mobile phones being used.

Answer (score 3):

I just usually long-press the item until I get the popup menu from the browser, press `back` to hide the menu and the hover is activated. Not a foolproof method but works most of the time. This way I can be *almost* sure that the tap doesn't send a click event.

Tested on 3.2, 4.0, 4.0.2 vanilla browsers and Chrome/Chrome beta on ICS.